# starting container process caused "exec: \".\": executable file not found

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, docker-container

i am new in docker. i want to deploy my application node js  in docker but i am facing below error kindly help me this

> /usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: oci runtime
>   error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused
>   "exec: \".\": executable file not found in $PATH".

```
 docker build -t project_account_v1:1.1 .
docker container run -e TZ=Asia/Karachi -d -p 9191:9191 project_account_v1:1.1 .
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.12

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app


ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN npm install

COPY . /app

VOLUME ["/app/logs"]

CMD ["node", "/app/app.js"]

EXPOSE 9191
```

Comment: How are you launching the container?  That `Dockerfile` doesn't obviously produce that error.

Comment: kindly check i add container cmmand

Comment: @DavidMaze kindly check command added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "exec: \".\": executable file not found in $PATH".

Remove the `.` at the end of the Docker run command.

Comment: not build the run command, `docker run -e TZ=Asia/Karachi -it -p 9191:9191 project_account_v1:1.1`